# append item to list at a random index os initial list

Tags: python, list, random

i have a list of answers to a quiz i a making, i would like to make it multiple choice and in multiple choice quizes the  answer is never at the bottom always or at the same index however this is what my code is

```
Answers = ["bogota", "carracas", "brasilia", "santiago", "london"]
Questions = ["colombia", "venezuela", "brasil", "chile", "england"]
q = [Questions[i] for i in sorted(random.sample(range(len(Questions)), 3))]
tryindex = [i for i, x in enumerate(QuestionsT) if x in q]
Ca = [Answers[i] for i in tryindex]
for x in q:
    Pa = [i for i in random.sample(Answers, 3) if i !=q.index(x)]
    Pa.append(Ca[q.index(x)])
    print("what is the capital of:" + x + "?")
    print("\n".join(Pa))
    a = input("\n""Answer")
    for i in range(0,3):
        if a == Ca[i]:
            score +=1
```

this returns eg for one iteration: 
what is the capital of: colombia?
london
carracas
brasilia
santiago
bogota

notice that bogota is at the bottom due to the .append(Ca[q.insert(x)])

what i would like is that the answer in this case would be inserted into Ca(correct answers) randomly. is there a way to do this?

- Answers means the genral list of all the answers possible Questions
  means the general list of all questions possible

  - in both of the above lists each element is reference by its index so
    that by finding the index of the element in Questions it is
    possible    to find the value held in Answers by the same index

  q means questions selected randomly for quiz 
  Ca means correct answers for questions in q. 
  Pa means possible answers, randomly obtained from the genral array Answers.

Comment: don't use indexes. Either randomize the zipped q & a together, or create a dict question => answer.

Comment: and your question & answer list doesn't have quotes. The code doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a clean solution, take a look, change what you want, ask for what you don't get.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Imports
import random

# Parameters
data = {'Brasil': 'Brasilia',
 'Chile': 'Santiago',
 'Colombia': 'Bogota',
 'England': 'London',
 'Venezuela': 'Carracas'}

nbr_questions = 3
score = 0
former_questions = ['']

# Script
for i in range(nbr_questions):
    # Grab the couple country / capital from the data dictionnary
    capital = ''
    while capital in former_questions:
        country, capital = random.choice(list(data.items()))

    # Create the proposition display list
    proposition_display = list()
    proposition_display.append(capital)
    i = 0
    while i < 2:
        cap = random.choice(list(data.values()))
        if cap not in proposition_display:
            proposition_display.append(cap)
            i += 1

    # Display
    print ('What is the capital of {} ?'.format(country))
    answer = input ('Answer: ')

    if answer.lower().strip(' ') == capital.lower().strip(' '):
        print ('Correct!')
        score += 1
    else:
        print ('Wrong. Answer was {}.'.format(capital))

    print ('-----------------------------')

    # Add this capital to the list former_questions to avoid repetition
    former_questions.append(capital)

print ('Your score is: {}'.format(score))
```